# css transition doesn't work properly on my card div

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am having issues figuring out what is wrong with my card div. I am trying to add in a little transition where the div pops up a little bit with a smooth animation but the transition doesn't work as it pops up instantly without any smooth animation.

```
.card-body {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ea5455;
  border-left: 1px solid #ea5455;
  border-right: 10px solid #ea5455;
  border-top: 1px solid #ea5455;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 30px;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  transform: translateY(0) scale(0.9, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(0.9, 0.9);
}

.card-body:hover,
.card-body:active {
  transform: translateY(-20px) scale(1, 1) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px) scale(1, 1) !important;
}
```

Here is a sandbox I made to show that the transition is not smooth and doesn't work but the transform does work: https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-problem-bp5dk

Comment: I realized that you are applying `fade` animation to the `.card-body` element. That's why the animation is prioritized over your transition. You can consider to move your transition to another element.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-problem-forked-6o7u3?file=/src/DegreeCard.js

Answer (score 1):

try adding the transition line
`transition: all .3s linear;`
into your hover and active pseudo classes

Comment: It stays the same

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and it works fine. Make sure that your current css file is already loaded (view the page source), it's common issue.

Comment: The css is loaded, that is why the transform is working but only transition doesn't work is my question

Comment: Transition works fine, I think there is a problem with css file. Try to put your css inside the  <style> tags in your index file and try again, it should work.

Comment: I am using React and I tried separately and it works but somehow it doesn't work on my actual project. I created a sandbox maybe you can have a look and see what is wrong and why the transition isn't smooth https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-problem-bp5dk